# UART fingerprint how to upload eigenvalue in python3 to the device

Tags: python, python-3.x, uart, fingerprint, eigenvalue

Has anybody had any experience with the waveshare UART fingerpirnt scanner.
https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/UART_Fingerprint_Sensor_(C)

I am want to upload the eigenvalue to the device and am not getting it right. The documentation explains how to do it but the demo code does not show how. I found a github where the option is there but it does not work. There seems to be a assert in the code that fails every time. So I comment this out.I tried to get hold of the developer .. no go.
https://github.com/sophianetSun/fingerprint-reader/blob/master/fingerprint.py

My process was to download the eigenvalue which I get in the form of a list.

```
[245, 0, 3, 2, 27, 9, 133, 166, 193, 32, 134, 19, 1, 40, 4, 33, 193, 65, 41, 25, 33, 66, 20, 91, 11, 73, 21, 22, 161, 77, 16, 218, 225, 80, 26, 88, 193, 15, 21, 42, 194, 18, 141, 81, 226, 24, 161, 88, 11, 45, 150, 123, 66, 8, 33, 25, 34, 59, 31, 2, 98, 23, 163, 64, 129, 26, 39, 26, 97, 37, 37, 218, 161, 45, 166, 28, 161, 53, 37, 94, 129, 80, 165, 85, 161, 86, 163, 22, 225, 93, 35, 87, 97, 99, 149, 91, 33, 97, 156, 25, 34, 96, 5, 221, 97, 105, 20, 27, 225, 110, 29, 26, 34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 124, 189, 245]
```

Then upload this to the device but it just hangs without any response, no response that says timeout or wrong format or anything. I dont think i am doing this right and have tried the following.

1. Save the eigenvalue to file using
   f = open("e.txt", "wb")
2. Read it back in
   f = open("e.txt", "wb")

But this just hangs.

I have stepped through the code checking every line and making sure the cheksums are right... nothing.
I have tried to change the eigenvalue list to hex, binary.... no go!

I even tried to email waveshare who gave me canned answers(Not really interested in helping)

Granted , I dont understand python and I am asking if anyone else has done this and can point me in the right direction.

This is how I am uploading my code:

```
class Command:
"""
Command definition
"""
CHK = 0
CMD_LEN = 8

HEAD = 0xF5
TAIL = 0xF5
ADD_1 = 0x01
ADD_2 = 0x02
ADD_3 = 0x03
DEL = 0x04
DEL_ALL = 0x05
USER_CNT = 0x09
COMP_LEV = 0x28
SLEEP = 0x2C
ADD_MODE = 0x2D
TIMEOUT = 0x2E

USER_PRI = 0x0A
COMP_ONE = 0x0B
COMP_MANY = 0x0C

ALL_USR = 0x2B

EXT_EGV = 0x23
UP_IMG = 0x24
VERSION = 0x26

UP_ONE_DB = 0x31

DOWN_ONE_DB = 0x41
DOWN_COMP_ONE = 0x42
DOWN_COMP_MANY = 0x43
DOWN_COMP = 0x44

  def read_reader(self, bytes_need, timeout):
    time_before = time.time()
    time_after = time.time()
    res = []
    while time_after - time_before < timeout and len(res) < bytes_need:
        res += self.ser.read(bytes_need)
        time_after = time.time()
    return res

   def send_cmd_packet(self, header, packet, rx_bytes_need):
    """
    send header and packet bytes
    :param header: bytes
    :param packet: bytes
    :param rx_bytes_need: int
    :return: bytes
    """
    # This makes no sense assert (Command(header[0]) == Command.HEAD and Command(header[-1]) == Command.TAIL), 'Data header error'
    header[-2] = get_chksum(header[1:-2])
    self.ser.flushInput()
    self.ser.write(header+packet)
    rx_buf = self.read_reader(rx_bytes_need, 1)

    if Ack(rx_buf[4]) == Ack.SUCCESS:
        return Response(Ack.SUCCESS, rx_buf)
    else:
        return Response(Ack(rx_buf[4]))

 def download_user_eigenvalue(self):
    """
    Client get user eigenvalue by user_id
    :param user_id: number
    :return: Response val binary
    """
    id_high, id_low = text_to_byte(3)# Download user 3
    cmd = [Command.HEAD, Command.UP_ONE_DB, id_high, id_low,
           0, 0, Command.CHK, Command.TAIL]
    res = self.send_command_response(cmd)
    # if res.ack == Ack.SUCCESS:
    #     res.val = res.val[1:-2]
    return res.val

    def add_fingerprint_by_data(self):
    """
    Module get eigen value and save the fingerprint by user id and privilege
    :param user_id: number
    :param user_pri: number or Privilege
    :param eigenvalue: binary data
    :return: Response val User
    """
    eigenvalue = [245, 0, 3, 2, 27, 9, 133, 166, 193, 32, 147, 19, 1, 40, 4, 33, 193, 65, 153, 25, 33, 66, 20, 91, 33, 73, 26, 66, 161, 77, 16, 218, 225, 80, 26, 88, 193, 15, 21, 42, 194, 18, 141, 81, 226, 24, 161, 88, 98, 45, 150, 218, 66, 8, 33, 25, 34, 59, 31, 2, 98, 23, 163, 64, 129, 26, 39, 26, 97, 37, 37, 218, 161, 45, 166, 28, 161, 53, 37, 94, 129, 80, 165, 85, 161, 86, 163, 22, 225, 93, 35, 87, 97, 99, 149, 91, 33, 97, 156, 25, 34, 96, 5, 221, 97, 105, 20, 27, 225, 110, 29, 26, 34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 124, 189, 245]
    #Drop off the first 4 bytes and the last 2 bytes. according to the docs
    eigenvalue = eigenvalue[4:197]# doc says that eigen must be 192bytes
    print(eigenvalue)
    print("length:", len(eigenvalue))


    id_high, id_low = text_to_byte(5)#upload as user 5
    high_len, low_len = int.to_bytes(len(eigenvalue), 2, 'big')
    cmd_header = [Command.HEAD, Command.DOWN_ONE_DB, high_len, low_len, 0, 0, Command.CHK, Command.TAIL]
    cmd_packet = [Command.HEAD, id_high, id_low, 2]#Group 2 of 1-3 groups of users
    cmd_packet += eigenvalue
    cmd_packet += [Command.CHK, Command.TAIL]
    cmd_packet[-2] = get_chksum(cmd_packet[1:-2])
    res = self.send_cmd_packet(cmd_header, cmd_packet, 8)
    # if res.ack == Ack.SUCCESS:
    #     res.val = User(id_high, id_low, user_pri)
    return res.val
```

Could not paste more code so
I used Pastelbin to show my code

https://pastebin.com/sREJpPap

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good effort on the question, but please show more of your own code.

Comment: Thank you .. I dont want to irrate to many people. I can paste the code in but its going to be a bit long. I am using the github code  https://github.com/sophianetSun/fingerprint-reader

Comment: Ok Thats the code I mave integrated into the version from github

Answer (score 0):

Please change
"high_len, low_len = int.to_bytes(len(eigenvalue), 2, 'big')" "to high_len, low_len = int.to_bytes(len(eigenvalue), 2, 'big')
low_len = 196".
It will respond.
Good luck to you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).